# Mailing Multiple Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already have figured out how to email users on a single basis (someone enters their email address and a mailer model sends that person an email using friend.email (friend being the model and email being the attribute).

Now I am trying to send an email to several users. I started writing a process in my User model like below:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic

  def mail_out

    weekday = Date.today.strftime(%A).downcase

    @users = find(:conditions => "#{weekday}sub = t")

    @users.each { |u| UserMailer.deliver_mail_out(u)}   


  end

end
```

I know there is probably a much better way to do this but each User in my database can have t or f for mondaysub, tuesdaysub, etc. So I want to throw all of the users with the attribute mondaysub set to "t" into the @monday variable (the same for each day of the week). Now I want to check the day of the week and if it's a monday, send an email to each of the users in the @monday variable.  I have used whenever as follows:

```
 every 1.day, :at => '5:30 am' do
    runner "User.mail_out"
  end
```

This will invoke the mail_out process in my model once a day (I think).

Now I have my mailer setup as follows:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def mail_out(users)
    @recipients = { }
    users.each do |user|
      @recipients[user.email] = { :name => user.name }
    end


    from        "no-reply@dailytrailer.net"
    subject     "Check out the trailer of the day!"
    body        :user => user
  end

end
```

My question is, how do I connect these together, I hope I am on the right track... I want it so every morning at 5:00, if its a monday, then every user with mondaysub set to "t" is mailed a specific usermailer template. I am starting to really confuse myself, any help would be GREATLY appreciative. As you can tell I am new at this but I have been reading through tons of books/tutorials.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of a bunch of finder methods, why not just have a `find_subscription_by_day` method that you pass the day to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of mass emailing you really ought to consider outsourcing the problem. Take a look at [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/) which makes it trivial to [email multiple recipients](http://postageapp.com/docs/rails). It's DHH-approved!

Answer (score 0):

Check [this railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email) about sending e-mails. You just need to create a template file for your e-mail on **views/usermailer/mail_out.erb.html**.

Comment: Thanks but I can create a template and do everything required to send a mail to one user. I need help sending mail to multiple users that meet a particular attribute condition.

Comment: Go for something like this on your Model method.

weekday = Date.today.strftime(%A).downcase
@users = find(:conditions => "#{weekday}sub = t")

  @users.each { |u| UserMailer.deliver_mail_out(u) }

Comment: I think I am getting it to work, I combined multiple answers. However I get an error in my user model, I updated my model above.

Comment: I get /home/tnederlof/Dropbox/Ruby/daily_trailer/app/models/user.rb:7: unknown type of %string
 weekday = Date.today.strftime(%A).downcase
                                  ^
/home/tnederlof/Dropbox/Ruby/daily_trailer/app/models/user.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
 weekday = Date.today.strftime(%A).downcase


When loading a user related page. Any ideas?